Azure Data Factory GitHub Actions getting the error message "The request content size exceeds the maximum size of 4 MB."
Originally we set up Azure Data Factory (ADF) using a GitHub repository.  We then set up GitHub Actions to deploy our code base from our DEV environment to our PRD environment. We were able to get GitHub actions to work fine.  But then the # of ADF Pipelines grew to over 200 and we're now getting this error message when running the GitHub deployment from DEV to PRD:
ERROR: {"code": "RequestContentTooLarge", "message": "The request content size exceeds the maximum size of 4 MB."}
I've read the documentation offered by Microsoft at these links:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery-linked-template...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-tutorial-linked-...
But it's not clear to me, how do specifically modify the YAML file presented in this technical document from Microsoft.
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/fasttrack-for-azure/azure-data-factory-ci-cd-with-github-actions/bc-p/4232307#M1011
The above link worked originally just fine until the ADF grew to over 200 pipelines where the ARM template exceeded 4 MB.  I know there's a 4 MB limit for ARM templates.  And the documentation says to use linked templates.
Please, can someone help me understand how to edit the YAML file to use the Linked Templates?
Does anyone have an updated YAML file that can utilize the available Linked Templates?
I see in the "adf_publish" branch a subfolder called "linkedTemplates." But I can't figure out how to use it or how to edit the YAML file to do so.
Below is all the code in the YAML called "main_prd.yml" file for reference:
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    branches:
    - main
permissions:
      id-token: write
      contents: read
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
# Installs Node and the npm packages saved in your package.json file in the build
    - name: Setup Node.js environment
      uses: actions/setup-node@v3.4.1
      with:
        node-version: 18.x
        
    - name: install ADF Utilities package
      run: npm install
      working-directory: ${{github.workspace}}/ADFroot/build  # (1) provide the folder location of the package.json file
        
# Validates all of the Data Factory resources in the repository. You'll get the same validation errors as when "Validate All" is selected.
    - name: Validate
      run: npm run build validate ${{github.workspace}}/ADFroot/ /subscriptions/77f8db5a-8430-4388-a8ba-c888b581226a/resourceGroups/JCG-EnterpriseDataWarehouse-00-rg/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/jcg-src-dev-00-adf # (2) The validate command needs the root folder location of your repository where all the objects are stored. And the 2nd parameter is the resourceID of the ADF instance 
      working-directory: ${{github.workspace}}/ADFroot/build
 
    - name: Validate and Generate ARM template
      run: npm run build export ${{github.workspace}}/ADFroot/ /subscriptions/77f8db5a-8430-4388-a8ba-c888b581226a/resourceGroups/JCG-EnterpriseDataWarehouse-00-rg/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/jcg-src-dev-00-adf "ExportedArmTemplate"  # (3) The build command, as validate, needs the root folder location of your repository where all the objects are stored. And the 2nd parameter is the resourceID of the ADF instance. The 3rd parameter is the exported ARM template artifact name 
      working-directory: ${{github.workspace}}/ADFroot/build
 
# In order to leverage the artifact in another job, we need to upload it with the upload action 
    - name: upload artifact
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: ExportedArmTemplate # (4) use the same artifact name you used in the previous export step
        path: ${{github.workspace}}/ADFroot/build/ExportedArmTemplate
  release:
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    
 # we 1st download the previously uploaded artifact so we can leverage it later in the release job     
      - name: Download a Build Artifact
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3.0.2
        with:
          name: ExportedArmTemplate # (5) Artifact name 
      - name: Login via Az module
        uses: azure/login@v2
        with:
          client-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CLIENT_ID }}
          tenant-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_TENANT_ID }}
          subscription-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}
          enable-AzPSSession: true 
      - name: data-factory-deploy
        uses: Azure/data-factory-deploy-action@v1.2.0
        with:
          resourceGroupName: JCG-EnterpriseDataWarehouse-00-rg
          dataFactoryName: jcg-src-prd-00-adf
          armTemplateFile: ARMTemplateForFactory.json
          armTemplateParametersFile: ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json
          additionalParameters: 
            'factoryName=jcg-src-prd-00-adf LS_ADLS_JCG_00_accountKey=${{ secrets.PRD_STORAGE_KEY }} LS_EDW_JCG_jcdwh_adf_admin_connectionString=${{ secrets.PRD_SQL_CONN_STRING }} LS_ADLS_JCG_00_properties_typeProperties_url=${{ secrets.PRD_STORAGE_URI }}'

          # skipAzModuleInstallation:  # Parameters which skip the Az module installation. Optional, default is false.​

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
After further investigation and following the instructions at this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/najib/deploying-linked-arm-templates-with-vsts
I did edit the YMAL file by replacing "ARMTemplateForFactory.json" with "linkedTemplates/ArmTemplate_master.json".
I then replaced "ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json" with "linkedTemplates/ArmTemplateParameters_master.json".
I then created the two GitHub Action Secrets called "CONTAINER_URI" and "CONTAINER_SAS_TOKEN".
I then added this to the "additionalParameters" as follows
containerUri=${{ secrets.CONTAINER_URI }}
containerSasToken=${{ secrets.CONTAINER_SAS_TOKEN }}'
Also, for the MANAGED IDENTITY called "ADF-UAMI", I added the following role assignments:
Contributor
Storage Blob Data Contributor
Storage Account Contributor
Storage Blob Data Owner
Storage Blob Data Reader
Also, I generated the SAS Token in the storage account as prescribed in the instructions.
At first, this seemed to have worked since it was able to find the "ArmTemplate_0.json" files.
But then I get the error "InvalidContentLink" and "Unable to download deployment content..."
For reference, below is the YAML code I used, and here is the complete error message:
ERROR: {"code": "InvalidContentLink", "message": "Unable to download deployment content from '/ArmTemplate_0.jsonsig=Sanitized Azure Storage Account Shared Access Signature'. The tracking Id is 'f6b674ad-7dbc-4434-96ea-6e56cb34daa6'. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deploy-resources for usage details."
Can someone let me know why I'm getting this error message?
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Here's the updated code at the bottom for reference:
with:
  resourceGroupName: JCG-EnterpriseDataWarehouse-00-rg
  dataFactoryName: jcg-src-uat-00-adf
  armTemplateFile: linkedTemplates/ArmTemplate_master.json
  armTemplateParametersFile: linkedTemplates/ArmTemplateParameters_master.json
  additionalParameters: 
    'factoryName=jcg-src-uat-00-adf containerUri=${{ secrets.CONTAINER_URI }} containerSasToken=${{ secrets.CONTAINER_SAS_TOKEN }}'


I was having the same error. What worked for me was adding the '?' at the beginning of the SAS token.
You can try to modify the parameters line like this:
containerSasToken=**?**${{ secrets.CONTAINER_SAS_TOKEN }}

Let me know if it worked!
